# Test Class for a Flow Apex Action plugin

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

Is it possible to create a unit test for an Apex class invoked in a Flow?

I have an Apex method that I can invoke through an Action in a FLOW called by an update to an object.  Is there any way to cover that inside of an Apex class?  I've been hearing rumors that we will need to start covering code in our Flows like we do in our Apex triggers, but I see no way to do that.

Comment: Are you trying to test the Flow? (use Flow Tests beta) or unit testing the invocable apex? If the latter, unit test it like any other apex class